# NullReferenceException when calling DbContext.Entry

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am facing this strange behavior that sometimes, when i try to Reload a Entry with:

```
DbEntityEntry<BatchServer> ent = d.Entry(jobServer);
//the ex is thrown at d.Entry
ent.Reload();
```

EF throws a `NullReferenceException` Exception. But neither `jobServer` nor `d` ( Variable of my Context ) is null and if we take a look into the StackTrace:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at System.Data.Objects.EntityEntry.DetectChangesInProperty(Int32 ordinal, Boolean detectOnlyComplexProperties, Boolean detectOnly)
at System.Data.Objects.EntityEntry.DetectChangesInProperties(Boolean detectOnlyComplexProperties)
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.DetectChangesInScalarAndComplexProperties(IList`1 entries)
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.DetectChanges()
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.DetectChanges()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.DetectChanges(Boolean force)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetStateEntry(Object entity)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalEntityEntry..ctor(InternalContext internalContext, Object entity)
at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.Entry[TEntity](TEntity entity)
at IEADPC.BatchRemoting.Monitor.ViewModel.MonitorViewModel.<>c__DisplayClass40.<>c__DisplayClass42.<RefreshAll>b__3d(BatchRemotingContexA first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in IEADPC.BatchRemoting.Monitor.dll
```

we see that there is a exception inside of EF. This bug is to 100% reproducible but only after a lot work in the program. So is that a known bug if EF or what am i doing wrong?

Greetings

**Update:**

Just befor i call this i get all server from the Context:

```
    DataAccessObject.ClientDataAccess.WorkOnDatabase(d =>
    {
        var colzwei = new ObservableCollection<BatchServer>(d.BatchServers.ToList());
        foreach (var jobServer in colzwei)
        {
            DbEntityEntry<BatchServer> ent;                                 
            ent = d.Entry(jobServer);
            ent.Reload();
            ...
        }
    }
```

---

```
    public void WorkOnDatabase(Action<BatchRemotingContext> databaseAction)
    {
        if (DbContext == null)
        {
            using (DbContext = ReturnDatabase())
            {
                databaseAction.Invoke(DbContext);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            databaseAction.Invoke(DbContext);
        }
    }
```

---

That works well in the whole program, just when i work in my program than it sometimes  happens

Comment: Is the exception happening at ent.Reload? Is ent null? Maybe the jobServer is no longer in the database?

Comment: What is d. did you set it?

Comment: @tofutim no the exception is happen at `d.Entry(...)`. `ent.Reload();` gets not executed.
@Robuust i did. I am using a function that ensures that i am allways working with a Valid connection. That works well in all other cases.

Comment: your `DbContext` is `BatchRemotingContext` or something else class?

Comment: It is the `BatchRemotingContext` class. There is not other Context in the whole Solution

Comment: do you try setup breakpoint and see value for `d` and `jobServer`?

Comment: i did. Is a valid object, eg. not null. and the call before `d.BatchServers.ToList()` is working fine. It returns the list with all items from the DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK the reason is strange as the bug self.

There is a other entity called: `ServerBatch` when i added them the first time, everything is OK. Then i edit them and add them the 2nd time to my list of Entitys. After that `SaveChanges` crash because i try to add the Entity with a PK to a list where the PK already exists. This crash is handled so the program will keep running and right after that crash the `Entry` method will fail and produce that Exception.